# Azure Functions - Block processing of Azure Service Bus messages

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Function (AF), that is triggered by Azure Service Bus messages. The messages are used to perform operations against another service. What I would like to do is that if there are transient failures in the service, then I would like to stop the message pump for a while. I do have Polly and a transient error policy to handle HTTP errors. But that allows me to retry after I have picked up a message. What I would like to do is to stop pulling messages for a while and then restart the pump. Is this possible with Azure Functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't block Azure Function. Instead, you disable it. That means it will require manual intervention. Documentation on how to disable Azure Functions is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function).

Comment: Thanks Sean. But how can I do this in code within the function app itself? The procedures described (like CLI, portal, etc), require human intervention. I would like the trigger to disable itself and possibly another time based trigger that would turn it back on.

Comment: Also, disabling looks like it works only at function startup. I would like a dynamic process, where when a circuit breaker is triggered, messages are not picked up until  the circuit is closed again.

Comment: A function cannot be paused at run time. Currently what triggers Service Bus function is a message in a queue. You will have to have a manual intervention or some custom code/logic to disable your function. Either way, the answer I've provided is what you asked: you can't unless it's manual 

Answer (score 1):

I recently was in this situation and built circuit breaker using App Insights ->Azure Monitor ->Azure Automation -> Disable Azure function. More details in the blog: https://medium.com/@binduc/circuit-breaker-pattern-for-azure-function-678ca0f7c3b5